# Increase my php laravel project version with every git commit and show in footer

Tags: php, git, laravel, build, version

I would like to show the version/build in my PHP Laravel project footer in a variable from Git.

I need someway to automatically store, update, commit the build version every time any of my developers do a Git commit using SourceTree/Bitbucket.

It is fine if something is already built into Git and if I can pull this straight from git and use that within my webpage PHP footer. It can be something simple and just reflect a string + timestamp to the second on every commit.

I do not know the best way or anyway to really do this and did not find any information that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually built using [`git describe`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe).

See for instance [tremby/laravel-git-version](https://github.com/tremby/laravel-git-version)

> A helper class to get the current git version of the project.

```
composer require tremby/laravel-git-version
\Tremby\LaravelGitVersion\GitVersionHelper::getVersion()
```

The [`GitVersionHelper.php`](https://github.com/tremby/laravel-git-version/blob/e6f6fc6edf5f1cd91575d34a9559519256f4d3e0/src/GitVersionHelper.php#L41-L42) does use:

```
    // Get version string from git
    $output = shell_exec('git describe --always --tags --dirty');
```

Comment: I can run the command manually in CLI but I am trying to run it inside the controller and it doesnt seem to update the version file using this "shell_exec('git describe --always --tags --dirty');"

Comment: Windows/Xampp PHP 7.1+. How can i run "git describe --always --tags --dirty" inside php code?

Comment: @Jonathan My answer shows that command running inside php code, so you can reuse said code within your own php code.

Comment: Except for said code doesn't update the version file and the @output variable is null...

Comment: @Jonathan It needs to be executed in a Git repo.